# how to know that a template systemctl has been stopped

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, systemctl

I think my question is similar to this one:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/941775/stopped-custom-services-controlled-by-systemd-do-not-appear-in-systemctl-list-un

But it didn't get any useful answer, so I try again !

What I need is to be able to know if a stopped template service has ever been started at all.

Here is my service:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/example@.service 
[Unit]
Description=Systemctl Example
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
StartLimitBurst=0

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/echo %i >> /opt/template.log
Restart=always
RestartSec=1s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

if I start then stop one instance of this service, it does not appear in the **list-units** list:

```bash
$ sudo systemctl start example@100
$ sudo systemctl start example@200
$ sudo systemctl stop example@200
$ systemctl list-units --full --all --plain --no-legend --no-pager|grep example
example@100.service                                                                                                loaded    activating auto-restart Systemctl Example
system-example.slice                                                                                               loaded    active     active       Slice /system/example
$ service example@100 status
● example@1.service - Systemctl Example
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/example@ [...]
     Active: activating (auto-restart) since Wed 2022-11-02 11:20:54 CET; 799ms ago
    Process: 41042 ExecStart=/bin/echo 100 >> /opt/template.log (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 4102 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms
nov. 02 11:20:54 systemd[1]: Started Systemctl Example.
nov. 02 11:20:55 echo[41042]: 100 >> /opt/template.log
nov. 02 11:20:54 systemd[1]: example@100.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

I would have expected the same behavior as the "not-template" service:

```bash
$ sudo systemctl stop bluetooth
$ systemctl list-units --full --all --plain --no-legend --no-pager|grep bluetooth
bluetooth.service                                                                                               loaded    inactive   dead         Bluetooth service
bluetooth.target                                                                                                loaded    active     active       Bluetooth Support
```

the **status** option is quite different if the service is template or no:

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2022-10-31 11:47:25 CET; 2min 18s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
    Process: 1071 ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1071 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Status: "Powering down"
        CPU: 56ms

$ systemctl status example@200 # this service instance has just been stopped
○ example@200.service - Systemctl Example
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/example@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

$ systemctl status toto@2000 # this service instance has never been started
○ example@2000.service - Systemctl Example
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/example@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

why is the "since xxxxxx; Ymin ago" is missing in the case of a template service ?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, but the same issue is also on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ systemctl --version
systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.6)
```

Comment: What do you see when you run `systemctl status` on a template that is currently running? (I'm currently overlooking the other issues you have in your service file; For instance, did you check that /opt/template.log actually get written?)

Comment: edited the question to join an example of the status while the service is running

Comment: @aviro: those services were more examples like real use-cases ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful for you:

```bash
sudo journalctl -xe -u example@200
```

That will show the logs about that unit (events such as start,finish,stop and more are handled by that command).

For example, in my case I stopped the unit `getty@tty1.service` and when I run `sudo journalctl -xe -u getty@tty1.service` I got this output:

```
Oct 31 20:53:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit getty@tty1.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit getty@tty1.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 13406.
Oct 31 20:53:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Deactivated successfully.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ The unit getty@tty1.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Oct 31 20:53:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on tty1.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit getty@tty1.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit getty@tty1.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 13406 and the job result is done
```

So you can `grep` the output above to determine if the unit has been stopped. But you might need to grep according to the date and hour.

In some cases the unit might have been finished successfully by itself. So instead of showing messages like `Stopped`,`Stopping` or `Deactivated` the output would be something like: `Finished X unit... Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully`.

**Tip 1**
If you want to get the journalctl output from or to specific date/time you can use the argument `--since` or `--until` and if you want to grep the output you can use the `--grep` option (so you avoid using a pipe like `journalctl  ... | grep something`). According to `man journalctl`

> -S, --since=, -U, --until=
>
> Start showing entries on or newer than the specified date, or on or older than the specified date, respectively. Date specifications should be of the format "2012-10-30 18:17:16". If the time part is omitted, "00:00:00" is assumed. If only the seconds component is omitted, ":00" is assumed. ...

> -g, --grep=
>
> Filter output to entries where the MESSAGE= field matches the specified regular expression. PERL-compatible regular expressions are used

So you can use something like this to get specific entry/entries:

```bash
sudo journalctl -xe -u example@200.service --since='2022-11-02 12:14'  --grep='Stopped'
```

**Tip 2:**
 If you were using **user units** (located in ~/.config/systemd/user/) then you should use: `journalctl -xe --user -u example@200`. If you use sudo for **user units** you might not be able to see any logs from that command (I'm not sure if this can be configured to be able to show the logs with sudo too)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. It's a little bit sad that I have to grep in the journal to get an information that is directly available for a non-template service. But it's a nice workaround !

Comment: @JulienGreard you could use `man journalctl`. It should show very useful information. I'll update the answer to provide a more functional way to get info according to status and date/time. (you can grep using the same journalctl command as well as you can specify the date)

Comment: thanks very much for the edit and the very useful info !

Comment: @JulienGreard you're welcome! Glad this was useful for you.